# How to create Neo4J relationship between nodes yelp dataset

Tags: neo4j

I am new to Neo4j. I am trying to populate Yelp dataset in Neo4j. Basically, I am interested in three json file provided by them i.e.

**user.json**

```
{
    "user_id": "-lGwMGHMC_XihFJNKCJNRg",
    "name": "Gabe",
    "review_count": 277,
    "yelping_since": "2014-10-31",
    "friends": ["Oa84FFGBw1axX8O6uDkmqg", "SRcWERSl4rhm-Bz9zN_J8g", "VMVGukgapRtx3MIydAibkQ", "8sLNQ3dAV35VBCnPaMh1Lw", "87LhHHXbQYWr5wlo5W7_QQ"],
    "useful": 45,
    "funny": 4,
    "cool": 55,
    "fans": 17,
    "elite": [],
    "average_stars": 4.72,
    "compliment_hot": 5,
    "compliment_more": 1,
    "compliment_profile": 0,
    "compliment_cute": 1,
    "compliment_list": 0,
    "compliment_note": 11,
    "compliment_plain": 20,
    "compliment_cool": 15,
    "compliment_funny": 15,
    "compliment_writer": 1,
    "compliment_photos": 8
}
```

I have omitted several entries from friends array to make output readable

**business.json**

```
{
    "business_id": "YDf95gJZaq05wvo7hTQbbQ",
    "name": "Richmond Town Square",
    "neighborhood": "",
    "address": "691 Richmond Rd",
    "city": "Richmond Heights",
    "state": "OH",
    "postal_code": "44143",
    "latitude": 41.5417162,
    "longitude": -81.4931165,
    "stars": 2.0,
    "review_count": 17,
    "is_open": 1,
    "attributes": {
        "RestaurantsPriceRange2": 2,
        "BusinessParking": {
            "garage": false,
            "street": false,
            "validated": false,
            "lot": true,
            "valet": false
        },
        "BikeParking": true,
        "WheelchairAccessible": true
    },
    "categories": ["Shopping", "Shopping Centers"],
    "hours": {
        "Monday": "10:00-21:00",
        "Tuesday": "10:00-21:00",
        "Friday": "10:00-21:00",
        "Wednesday": "10:00-21:00",
        "Thursday": "10:00-21:00",
        "Sunday": "11:00-18:00",
        "Saturday": "10:00-21:00"
    }
}
```

**review.json**

```
{
    "review_id": "VfBHSwC5Vz_pbFluy07i9Q",
    "user_id": "-lGwMGHMC_XihFJNKCJNRg",
    "business_id": "YDf95gJZaq05wvo7hTQbbQ",
    "stars": 5,
    "date": "2016-07-12",
    "text": "My girlfriend and I stayed here for 3 nights and loved it.",
    "useful": 0,
    "funny": 0,
    "cool": 0
}
```

As we can see in the sample files that relationship between user and business is associated via the `review.json` file. How can I create a relationship edge between `user` and `business` using the `review.json` file.

I have also seen Mark Needham tutorial where he has shown StackOverflow data population but in that case, relationship file was already present with sample data. Do I need to build a similar file? If yes, how should I approach this problem? or is there any other way to build relationship between user & business?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It very much depends on your model as to what you want to do, but you could do 3 imports:

```
//Create Users - does assume the data is unique
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///c://temp//SO//user.json') YIELD value AS user
CREATE (u:User)
SET u = user
```

then add the businesses:

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///c://temp//SO//business.json') YIELD value AS business
CREATE (b:Business {
            business_id     : business.business_id,
            name            : business.name,
            neighborhood    : business.neighborhood,
            address         : business.address,
            city            : business.city,
            state           : business.state,
            postal_code     : business.postal_code,
            latitude        : business.latitude,
            longitude       : business.longitude,
            stars           : business.stars,
            review_count    : business.review_count,
            is_open         : business.is_open,
            categories      : business.categories
        })
```

For the businesses, we can't just do the `SET b = business` because the JSON has nested maps. So you might want to decide if you want them, and might have to go down a different route.

Lastly, the reviews, which is where we join it all up.

```
CALL apoc.load.json('file:///c://temp//SO//review.json') YIELD value AS review
CREATE (r:Review)
SET r = review
WITH r
//Match user to a review
MATCH (u:User {user_id: r.user_id})
CREATE (u)-[:HAS_REVIEW]->(r)
WITH r, u
//Match business to a review, and a user to a business
MATCH (b:Business {business_id: r.business_id})
//Merge here in case of multiple reviews
MERGE (u)-[:HAS_REVIEWED]->(b)
CREATE (b)-[:HAS_REVIEW]->(r)
```

Obviously - change labels/relationships to types you want, and it might need tuning depending on the size of data etc, so you might need to use `apoc.periodic.iterate` to work it.

Apoc is [here](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) if you need it (and you should use it!)

Comment: Thanks for your help, much appreciated. Can you please tell me how to create friends relationship i.e. in user record between user_id & friends array. I tried it the same way as review but it is going on forever. Thanks again